# Using TFS intellij and Coldfusion just .cfm files are locked when I edit a file

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, coldfusion

I'm using intellij TFS and ColdFusion. When I edit a file it is not locked except the `.cfm` files. When I look the TFS Version Control Information just the `.cfm` are locked. Where can I set the extension file list or what I should do to lock all files instead of using eclipse cold fusion IDE ? I'm using intellij ULTIMATE EAP 2018.1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your IDE will respect the setting, but you can try changing the checkout settings for the project as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/configure-check-out-settings

Comment: no I can't, everyone use eclipse cold fusion and we can not change the configuration. Everything is working fine with eclipse coldfusion

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, in IntelliJ TFS one can only lock/unlock files with a specific command in the context menu.

Moreover, the lock is not indicated in the UI - see
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124635

Comment: in intellij when I edit a file, if it is not a .cfm the file is not locked.